# PHP Cron Event for Unzipping

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, zip

I'm trying to create a cron job, based on the below code to periodically unzip a .zip file on my server, but keep getting thrown header errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction please. Its within a Wordpress installation:

```
<?php 
$zip = zip_open("/tmp/test2.zip"); 
if ($zip) { 
 while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) { 
   echo "Name:              " . zip_entry_name($zip_entry) . "\n"; 
   echo "Actual Filesize:    " . zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry) . "\n"; 
   echo "Compressed Size:    " . zip_entry_compressedsize($zip_entry) . "\n"; 
   echo "Compression Method: " . zip_entry_compressionmethod($zip_entry) . "\n";

   if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) { 
       echo "File Contents:\n"; 
       $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry)); 
       echo "$buf\n"; 

       zip_entry_close($zip_entry); 
   } 
   echo "\n"; 
} 
zip_close($zip); 
} 
?>
```